# React-loadable warning text content did not match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I use `react-loadable` for dynamically loading JS modules. I also use server-side rendering, which is set up and works for `react-loadable`. On the client side, however, there seems to be a problem, because when I load the page a warning appears in the console:

```
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Choose a name and enter passwordNamePasswordLogin" Client: "Loading..."
```

I use `preloadReady` on the client side, which should prevent this error.

My `index.jsx` looks like this:

```
import { preloadReady } from 'react-loadable';

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {    
  await preloadReady();

  hydrate(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
});
```

Package versions:

- Node: `v8.12.0`
- webpack: `4.19.1`
- webpack-cli: `3.1.1`
- @babel/core: `7.1.0`
- babel-loader: `8.0.2`
- react-loadable: `5.5.0`

**Edit:**

So I realized, that the server-side part of `react-loadable` doesn't actually work, because it can't get the list of bundles to include. The cause of this is that `Loadable.Capture` doesn't fire the `report` callback, and so the `modules` array will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I made a very basic mistake, which was that I tried to use `getBundles` on the server side after the react app was defined, but before it was rendered. So obviously the `report` callback wasn't called as it is called at render time. After I changed the code to get the bundles *after* rendering, it works just fine (although I still have the problem of bundle duplicates, but I can easily filter that).

Answer (score 0):

If András's solution doesn't resolve the issue. Then in your served .html file, ensure that chunk's script is available before vendor and main bundle. So, reorder chunk JS before vendor and main JS.

```
<script src="chunk.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor.js" defer></script>
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
```